# Foreign-Keys: Simple query not working

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I can't seem to get the following MySQL-Query to work:

```
CREATE TABLE task_one_line (
    `timestampStart` BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    `userId` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`timestampStart`, `userId`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB


CREATE TABLE task_one_included_object (
    `objectId` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    `timestampStart` BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    `userId` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`objectId`, `userId`, `timestampStart`), 
    FOREIGN KEY(`userId`, `timestampStart`) REFERENCES task_one_line (`userId`, `timestampStart`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB
```

It gives:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'crowdtracker.task_one_included_object' (errno: 150)
```

Which according to the MySQL-Manual indicates an error with foreign-key constrains. But all foreign keys have the same constraints as the referenced attributes so I can not understand the error. What am I missing?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order makes a difference in the reference to the primary key.  You have the references as `timestampStart, userId`.  It should be in the other order:

```
CREATE TABLE task_one_line (
    `timestampStart` BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    `userId` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (userId, `timestampStart`)
);

CREATE TABLE task_one_included_object (
    `objectId` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    `timestampStart` BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    `userId` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`objectId`, `userId`, `timestampStart`), 
    FOREIGN KEY(`userId`, `timestampStart`) REFERENCES task_one_line (`userId`, `timestampStart`)
);
```